# handle multiple accounts on one computer with redux to store shopping items in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, redux, next.js, frontend

I have e-commerce website and I want to handle multiple accounts in one computer like when user switches between different accounts the data which is related to account get shown like shopping carts items.
for this I define my redux like this:

```
 const initialState = {
  carts: {},
};
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "profile",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
     
      if (state.carts[action.payload.id]) {
        const itemExists = state.carts[action.payload.id].find(
          (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
        );
        if (itemExists) {
          itemExists.quantity++;
        } else {
          state.carts[action.payload.id].push({
            ...action.payload.item,
            quantity: 1,
          });
        }
        toast(`${action.payload.title} added`);
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          carts: {
            ...state.carts,
            [action.payload.id]: [
              ...state.carts[action.payload.id],
              { ...action.payload.item, quantity: 1 },
            ],
          },
        };
      }
    },
    incrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      item.quantity++;
    },
    decrementQuantity: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.cart.find((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      if (item.quantity === 1) {
        const index = state.cart.findIndex(
          (item) => item.id === action.payload
        );
        state.cart.splice(index, 1);
      } else {
        item.quantity--;
      }
    },
    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      const index = state.cart.findIndex((item) => item.id === action.payload);
      state.cart.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
});
```

and in component I have

```
onClick={() =>
            dispatch(
              addToCart({
                item,
                id: data.user.user.id,
              })
            )
          }
```

but I receive state.carts[action.payload.id] is undefined.

my final state should be like this:

```
{
carts:{
id1:[shopping carts items],
id2:[shopping carts items],
.
.
.
}
}
```

Comment: So store in in a key based on the logged in user....

Comment: yes I want to store shopping cart items key based but I receive undefined in reducer